# Почему не работает change в форме?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, form, onchange

Вот часть формы. Нужно сохранять выбранные значения в `localStorage`. Пытаюсь это сделать по событию `change`. Всё хорошо, но вот с блоками класса `radioBtn` возникла заминка. Дело в том, что значение в соответствующих *скрытых инпутах* устанавливаются по клике на определённую *ссылку*. Странно, почему-то скрипт не видит изменения в этих *инпутах*.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#big_form', function(e) {
  console.log(12)
  localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/big_form/" class="mt-3" id="big_form">
  <div class="row">
    <input class="form-control" id="sum2" name="big-sum2" type="number">
    <select id="" name="big-currency2">
      <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Форма выдачи</label>
    <div class="radioBtn btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="tumbler_1" data-title="1">Наличными</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="tumbler_1" data-title="2">На счет</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="tumbler_1" data-title="3">На карту</a>
    </div>
    <input id="tumbler_1" name="big-issue_form" type="hidden" value="3">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="little" style="width: 362px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ок</button>
</form>
```

Можно, конечно выставить `onclick` на ссылки, но это не совсем верное решение, что-то мне подсказывает.

Comment: Для изменений, сделанных скриптом, событие change не запускается.

Comment: Понял... Тогда `onclick` на ссылки вешать всё-таки?

Comment: `но это не совсем верное решение`. Использовать Bootstrap, чтобы стилизовать ссылки под кнопки, имитирующие поведение радиокнопок, чтобы изменить значение в скрытом поле... хм )

Comment: это к фронтовщику вопросы... но мне тоже это не понравилось изначально.

Comment: Поругать его надо и ссылку дать [Checkbox and radio buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)